# ViewPager как реализовать вместо текста imgbutton

Tags: android

Помогите пожалуйста как вместо надписей реализовать imgbatton. Имеется ViewPager состоящий из 3 фрагментов как  сделать чтобы перелистывание помимо слайда происходило от кнопок?
Вот проект https://cloud.mail.ru/public/2401cb466dc6/Slide.rar
[Сейчас так](http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=877470840f6d5cc90af43a89e691b9a7)

[А надо примерно так](http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=33f0c07f4a24aaf29396c8ed2cc95abd)

Answer (score 1):

А причем здесь textview и imgbutton? Вы юзаете фрагменты,а что будет в них решать Вам.Описываете свой адаптер, нужные Вам фрагменты и вперед ))

---

update: картинки не видны

[пример от гугла](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)

[подключить актион бар для младших версий](http://habrahabr.ru/post/189680/)

Comment: У меня не получается описать адаптер чтобы вверху отображались 3 imgbutton и чтобы перелистывание помимо свайпа происходило от нажатия на эти imgbutton. И чтобы на всех 3ех pages были эти 3 imgbutton.
ps ссылки поправил

Comment: This image could not be loaded ( посмотреть не получается но не суть,как я понимаю Вам нужна навигация по табам со свайпом. Можно использовать actionBar  c NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS и viewpager

Comment: А вы можете дать ссылку на что то похожее?

Comment: добавил пару ссылок, но основы почитать все равно нужно - рекомендовал бы нормально разобраться с фрагментами, viewpager  и адаптерами

Comment: Swipe Views with Tabs - это почти тоже самое, что у меня есть сейчас. А мне надо, чтобы вместо надписей (Tab1, Tab2, Tab3)или как у меня сейчас (page1,page2,page3) ,были картинки(иконки)!!!!

Comment: так в табы иконок добавить и будет счастье

Comment: -) если бы все так просто -) 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVahIc8yENk
судя по этому (так в табы иконок добавить и будет счастье) - так сделать нельзя

Comment: больше читайте мануалы, видио не  дают полной картины. Метод setIcon принесет вам гармонию, умиротворение  и подарит вам долгожданное счастье )  так же если желаете постигнуть дзен можно использовать свои view вместо табов